# How to check if a function is continuous on some interval?

Tags: functions, continuity, numerical-methods

What the methods exists for check ["Jump discontinuity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) on some interval?

I am interested in numerical methods because I need to implement this in a high-level, general-purpose programming language

**Example:**

Input: $f(x)=\arctan2(x,-1)$, Interval $[-1,+1]$

Output: The discontinuity [exists](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/havrghvyrw).

<sub>Of Course, any function($f:R \rightarrow R$) and any interval can be input</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Comment: May be this idea helps you:

We use inverse function. Let's use the example in your reference:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    x^2       ,& x<1 \\
    0         ,& x=1 \\
    2-(x-1)^2 ,&  x>1
\end {cases}$

$f(x)$ is discontinuous in $x_0=1$. Inverse function $f(y)$ is:

$f(y)=\begin{cases}
    \pm\sqrt y     ,& y>1\\
    0              ,& y=1 \\
    0              ,& y=2 \\
    1\pm\sqrt{2-y} ,& y<2
\end{cases}$

$f(y)$ is discontinuous in interval $1< y< 2$.

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous if the change in $y$ decreases as the change in $x$ decreases. That is to say, as $\Delta x\to0$, one must have $\Delta y\to0$.

A simple procedure to find where this does not occur would be to sample a bunch of points over an interval of interest.

- Consider every other point, $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_{i+2},y_{i+2})$, and compute $\Delta y$.
- Then compare with consecutive pairs of points, $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$, and its $\Delta y$.
- If $\Delta y$ does not seem to go to $0$, then repeat this procedure on a more refined level over that interval until you want to consider the point a discontinuity (for example, repeat until $\Delta x<0.001$).